# Mixing both gluten production and milk

Tags: bread, pizza, sourdough

I would like to get tenderness from both the leavening and the milk, when and where I should add the milk ?

My recipe is based on sourdough starter, wheat flour and water, plus oil and salt.

I'm asking this because I know that the milks alters the actions and the production of the gluten, but the gluten is essential for leavening .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only practical time to add milk is at the beginning of dough formation, when you can still stir the flour and liquid together.  Trying to add milk (or any liquid) after the dough has formed is very difficult.

While it may very slightly retard gluten development, additional kneading or resting time will make up for this.

Comment: so it's "ok" but the final dough will require more time to double ?

Comment: Yes, though the effect may be small.  It is usually accounted for in whatever recipe you are using.  As a beginner, you definitely want to be working from well tested recipes which are going to give you good results, and not improvising.